# How do I modify the code of a merge request before merging in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

The scenario is as follows: A user has opened a merge request that adds a new feature to my code. Their code however contains a few bugs. I know how to fix the appropriate parts but I'd prefer keeping my repository free of code that has known issues. Therefore I'd like to modify their code before merging it.

I know I could also manually copy over the changes but I would still like to give the user that opened the merge request credit for their contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the user's changes (pull them over to your development environment) using Git, and then add your changes, and then merge the lot -- this way your user's commits are visible, and your commits are visible.

You could also add your user to a CREDITS file to give them credit as a contributor.

You could also ask the user to fix the bugs (which helps the user too, to learn how to improve their code) and then merge the change.